# Is there any posibity way to check whether the source code of an app from the store version?s

Tags: applications

I'm an accessibility auditor. I've been working on auditing web pages following the WCAG standard for years, but now I need to audit a mobile app.

Most of the criteria are quite similar to audit, but for some of them, like "4.1.1 Parsing," I'm encountering real struggles. I need to check that the app does not contain any errors and does not use any deprecated functions. However, I only have access to the store version, not the source code.

Is there any way to check that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: By "store" you mean the Google Play Store? I suspect if even 1% apps on Play Store are open-source. Check https://f-droid.org for a handful of open-source apps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and yes, a mean Google Play Store, but the app is not open-source.  Maybe there is some tool such https://validator.w3.org/ where to check it

Comment: Some sort of reverse engineering is possible https://github.com/AmrAshraf/AndroShield but the app itself might be actively trying to avoid that analysis, in which case it would be impossible to assert the app behaviour.

Comment: "does not contain any errors" - what type of errors are you talking about? Verifying that a certain program or app is free of errors is impossible (-> theoretical computer science). Also for Android apps are running on different Android versions from different manufacturer. Code that works on one device may not work on a different device. The same for deprecated functions (why does an accessibility check contain a deprecated functions check)?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I don't know the details of your task, but based on my experience with app audits, the auditor works together with the developer to provide the necessary data, including screenshots of source code.

Comment: Thank you Martheen, I'll look it up.

Comment: Robert, sorry for not being clear enough. In a web-only application, I'd check that W3C standards are met, you know ... tags are properly closed, not repeated IDs... The regulations to be followed are based on recommendations originally created for websites, but they are now also being demanded for apps (without having adapted those recommendations beforehand). Therefore, it's not entirely clear what "errors" should be reviewed, but essentially, it means ensuring that the app is structurally well-formed.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew T. I wish I could work with the developers; it would simplify my life, but this time it's not the case